# Change mysitephp?id=username to username.php with mod rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Say I have members and when they log in they go to `mysite.php/id=username`, where username is always different depending on their actual username.

Could I use one line in mod rewrite to strip the id= and just leave the username? How would I do that?

Example: `mysite.php?id=john` - I want it to be `mysite/john`, and the same for others.

Comment: Who down-voted my question and why?

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite `/mysite/john` to `/mysite.php?id=john` you would use:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^mysite/([^/]+) mysite.php?id=$1 [L]
```

You can test this rule here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just do this:

```
RewriteRule ^mysite/([A-za-z0-9-]+).php$ mysite.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This assumes that userids are letters (upper and lower case), numbers or dashes.  Add characters to the regex that are appropriate for you.  Of course you could just do `.+` to match anything, but I don't like to make things that wide open.

Comment: You are missing underscores in usernames... I would probably use `[^/]` for the character class.

Comment: As I said, it depends on what character space the usernames use.  I would highly recommending whitelisting the characters that are allowed, as opposed to blacklisting the ones that can't be (ie just slashes)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+).php$ mysite.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: that would rewrite `username.php` to `mysite.php?id=username`

Comment: thanks for answering but I want it the other way around. I thought that was clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `mod_rewrite` for this, you could try `mod_substitute` (make sure that `mod_filter` is also enabled):

```
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute s|/?index\.php\?id=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|/index/$1/|i
```

Not sure how good this will work though, haven't tested it.

Then you can use `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:**

I think I've misunderstood your question, if you're trying to change the URL in the address bar form `index.php?id=username` to `index/username` this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index/%1/? [R,L]
```